# webpack referring to a type without a variable

Tags: angular, webpack

running

```
yarn run webpack:dev`
```

is no problem, but

```
yarn run webpack:prod:
```

produces this error:

```
 ERROR in Illegal State: referring to a type without a variable
{"filePath":"E:/****/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/antd.d.ts","name":"ɵet","members":[]}
```

"@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",

Comment: Give us more information, about your code, the piece of code that is breaking, the full stack trace, your config, so on and so forth. Without it, no one can answer your question.