# jhipster Project won't build for prod profile : gradlew -Pprod bootWar fails on taks webpack

Tags: gradle, webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg

### ISSUE SOLVED see below for infos

after searching for a solutions for 2 days now i give up. I coudn't find a similar issue on the web and i don't know what to do.

Hope somebody can help there...

### Issue

The application is building and running fine with `gradlew -Pdev bootWar jibDockerBuild`

However, the build won't work when selecting the prod profile:
`gradlew -Pprod bootWar jibDockerBuild`

### Reference Exception

```
ERROR in Illegal State: referring to a type without a variable
{"filePath":"D:/dev/myApp/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts",
"name":"FormGroupDirective","members":[]}
```

### FULL EXCEPTION

The following is printed on execution:

```
D:\dev\myApp>gradlew -Pprod bootWar jibDockerBuild
> Task :yarn_install
yarn install v1.9.4
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@4.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3".
warning " > bootstrap@4.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.14.3".
warning " > ngx-webstorage@2.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^5.0.0".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
Done in 97.47s.

> Task :webpack
yarn run v1.9.4
$ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
$ rimraf build/{aot,www}
$ yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
(node:28256) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Hash: 6aab3d14e434ee333c51
Version: webpack 4.8.0
Time: 8812ms
Built at: 2018-10-07 18:52:03
 6 assets
Entrypoint polyfills = app/polyfills.6aab3d14e434ee333c51.bundle.js
Entrypoint global = global.1e92ecdbfdaf2bb32590.css app/global.6aab3d14e434ee333c51.bundle.js
Entrypoint main = app/main.6aab3d14e434ee333c51.bundle.js
[0] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 0 bytes {0} [built]
    factory:4638ms building:3545ms = 8183ms
[2] ./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 39 bytes {1} [built]
    factory:4639ms building:2778ms = 7417ms
[3] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {2} [built]
    factory:4638ms building:3540ms = 8178ms
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in Illegal State: referring to a type without a variable {"filePath":"D:/dev/myApp/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts","name":"FormGroupDirective","members":[]}
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

> Task :webpack FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webpack'.
> Process 'command 'yarn.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

### ENVIRONMENT

Windows 10

Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
Executing jhipster:info
Options: from-cli: true
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

**JHipster Version(s)**

```
myApp@0.0.0 D:\dev\myApp
`-- generator-jhipster@5.4.1
```

**JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**

```
<details>
<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
<pre>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "de.myApp.myApp",
      "nativeLanguage": "de"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.4.1",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "myApp",
    "packageName": "de.myApp.myApp",
    "packageFolder": "de/myApp/myApp",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "de",
    "languages": [
      "de",
      "en",
      "fr"
    ],
    "appsFolders": [
      "myApp"
    ],
    "directoryPath": "../",
    "monitoring": "elk",
    "consoleOptions": [
      "curator"
    ],
    "jwtSecretKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons"
  }
}
</pre>
</details>
```

**JDL for the Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

SKIPPED

**Environment and Tools**

java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0

node: v8.11.3

npm: 5.6.0

yarn: 1.9.4

Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with just the `.yo-rc.json`, it may be related to one of the entity forms

Comment: Similar Error message in a different question:
referring to a type without a variable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871904/webpack-referring-to-a-type-without-a-variable

Comment: @JonRuddell do you have an idea how i could find that out?

Comment: I tried on a vanilla project and the build was working just fine. It must have to do with the reactive forms i'm using, but I can't takle the reason. The exeption is just not providing enough information. I tried with DEBUG logging and --stacktrace options without meaningful information.

Comment: Could you add a simple reactive form to the post that reproduces the issue?

Comment: indeed i thought of trying to make a vanilla project with the most simplest reactive form according to documentation to see if i can somehow nail down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue:

I obviously placed the ReactiveFormModul imports at the wrong place. I had it in a module "upwards", but actually, I had to place it into the module where I actually have the components defining the form. To be honest ... I don't understand exactly why this is an issue, maybe someone can clarify.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

*** other imports

@NgModule({
    imports: [***, ReactiveFormsModule, *** ROUTER stuff,
    declarations: [MyReactiveFormComponent],
    schemas: [***]
})
export class MyReactiveFormModule {}
```

After this, I found also other issues that was working fine in the dev-build (again ... don't understand the reason. I guess that has to do with a stricter "compile" configuration):

1. The variable referencing the formGroup was declared "private". Therefore I got a compile Error on the prod profile. I had to change it so that it can be accessed by the html template.
2. Variables accessed in html must be public (or accessible by means of a getter method)
3. Accessing Form Controls in subsequent html elements must be "public"

Code-Example: 
MyReactiveComponent.ts:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            id: [this.myObject.id],
            date: [this.myObject.date, Validators.required],
            number: [this.myObject.number, [Validators.required, Validators.min(2), Validators.max(100)]],
            dynamicOptions: this.fb.array([]),
            prefilledOptions: [this.prefilledOptions, Validators.required]
        });
```

MyReactiveComponent.html:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-8">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" id="myFormId" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
        <h2>Create or edit a Play</h2>
        <div>
            <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="number" (blur)="updateNumber()" id="field_number" required min="2" jhiMin="2" max="100" jhiMax="100"/>
                <div [hidden]="!(number?.dirty && number?.invalid)">
                    <small class="form-text text-danger"
                    [hidden]="!number?.errors?.required">
                    This field is required.
                    </small>
...
```

Accessing number in "number?.dirty" for example requires to have a getter-method to be able to access it:

```
get number() {
    return this.myForm.get('number') as FormControl;
}
```

Hope that helps other when struggling...